# Cypress: type tab key

Tags: testing, e2e-testing, cypress

I want to test that my forms are accessible and that I can tab between my input elements. I found this github issue asking for the feature here:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/299

Currently I try to do `.type('{tab}')` and I get the following error:

> CypressError: {tab} isn't a supported character sequence. You'll want to use the command cy.tab(), which is not ready yet, but when it is done that's what you'll use.

Is there a current workaround for the lack of tab support?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Cypress team is currently working on implementing `tab` support along with other keyboard keys as part of [`Native Events`](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/311)

In the meantime I've made a plugin that adds a `.tab()` command. [`cypress-plugin-tab`](https://github.com/Bkucera/cypress-plugin-tab):

[image]

This enables you to do:

```js
cy.get('input').tab()
// and
cy.get('input').tab({shift: true})
```

**However**, the actual tab implementation will not be a separate command, so know if you use this plugin, you'll have to refactor your test code when Native Events lands

As the [cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type#Tabbing) says:

> In the meantime, you can use the experimental [`cypress-plugin-tab`](https://github.com/Bkucera/cypress-plugin-tab) and can thumbs up [this issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/299).

Comment: Hi bkucera, this did the magic for me. I improved the performance of a legacy combo box using this. I just  type the text and invoked the tab function so that the value is selected. Hope this approach won't make any undesired behaviors. Using this I reduced test execution time from 40-50 seconds to 25 seconds

Comment: Does it can be imported in .ts?

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan Yeah it has good TypeScript support :)

Comment: Does not seem to work in Cypress 12 :( No such command ...

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend to use the [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events#cyrealpress) plugin:

```
cy.realPress('Tab');
// or
cy.get('input').realPress('Tab');
```

Because the *cypress-plugin-tab* seems no longer to work natively since Cypress 10 and it's no longer maintained:
[Update plugin to be compatible with Cypress 10](https://github.com/kuceb/cypress-plugin-tab/issues/61)