# How to add cypress-plugin-tab to my Angular e2e testing?

Tags: angular, cypress, angular-e2e, nomachine-nx

I am using Angular12, NX, Cypress & KendoUI.
I need to test tabbing through form elements.
How do I add cypress-plugin-tab to my e2e testing?

The guide says use require in the suppport/index.ts file - this is not working for me.

I have executed `npm install -D cypress-plugin-tab` and added `require('cypress-plugin-tab')` to suppport/index.ts
I have added this code to my test:

```
   let password = 'Password';
   let input = cy.focused();
   
   input.type(username).tab().type(password);
```

This does not work as it says it cannot find 'tab'.
How do I get 'tab' to work in Angular?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress: type tab key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55009332/cypress-type-tab-key)

Answer (score 4):

You need to add in tsconfig.json in compilerOptions > types the cypress-plugin-tab src path.

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": ["node", "cypress", "cypress-plugin-tab/src"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
```